# joinmonster is not a function - GraphQL

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, graphql

I am using the library join-monster with GraphQL and postgres, with GraphiQL as client. When querying the database, I got the error: "joinMonster is not a function".
The method joinMonster() is provided by the library and is used in the resolvers.

The connection to the database is by knex and, apparently, it works. if I run the following code, I get the data form the table:

```
knex('students').then(rows => console.log(rows))
```

[Database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzQlO.png)

[GraphiQL outpup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHcOC.png)

This is the schema-resolvers code:

```js
const joinMonster = require('join-monster');

const knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'postgres',
    connection: {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'postgres',
    password: 'myPassword',
    database: 'test'
  }
});

const { graphQLSchema } = require("graphql");

const {
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLNonNull,
  GraphQL
} = require('graphql');

const Subject = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Subject",
  sqlTable: 'subjects',
  uniqueKey: 'id',
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      type: GraphQLInt
    },
    name: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    idEncoded: {
      description: 'The ID base-64 encoded',
      type: GraphQLString,
      sqlColumn: 'id',
      // specifies SQL column and applies a custom resolver
      resolve: user => toBase64(user.idEncoded)
    },
    teacher: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    students: {
      type: new GraphQLList(Student),
      junction: {
        sqlTable: 'class',
        sqlJoins: [
          (subjectTable, junctionTable, args) => `${subjectTable}.id = ${junctionTable}.subject_id`,
          (junctionTable, studentTable, args) => `${junctionTable}.student_id = ${studentTable}.id`
        ]
      }
    }
  })
});

const Student = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Student",
  sqlTable: 'students',
  uniqueKey: 'id',
  fields: () => ({
    id: {
      type: GraphQLInt
    },
    name: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    idEncoded: {
      description: 'The ID base-64 encoded',
      type: GraphQLString,
      sqlColumn: 'id',
      resolve: user => toBase64(user.idEncoded)
    },
    lastname: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    subjects: {
      type: new GraphQLList(Subject),
      junction: {
        sqlTable: 'class',
        sqlJoins: [
          (studentTable, junctionTable, args) => `${studentTable}.id = ${junctionTable}.student_id`,
          (junctionTable, subjectTable, args) => `${junctionTable}.subject_id = ${subjectTable}.id`
        ]
      }
    }
  })
});

const QueryRoot = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: () => ({
    student: {
      type: Student,
      args: {
        id: {
          type: GraphQLInt
        }
      },
      where: (studentsTable, args, context) => {
        if (args.id) return `${studentsTable}.id = ${args.id}`
      },
      resolve: (parent, args, context, resolveInfo) => {
        return joinMonster(resolveInfo, {}, sql => {
          return knex.raw(sql)
        })
      }
    },

    subject: {
      type: Subject,
      args: {
        id: {
          type: GraphQLInt
        }
      },
      where: (subjectsTable, args, context) => {
        if (args.id) return `${subjectsTable}.id = ${args.id}`
      },
      resolve: (parent, args, context, resolveInfo) => {
        return joinMonster(resolveInfo, {}, sql => {
          return knex.raw(sql)
        })
      }
    }
  })
})


const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: QueryRoot,
});

module.exports = schema;

function toBase64(clear) {
  return Buffer.from(String(clear)).toString('base64')
}
```

I have followed the documentation from https://join-monster.readthedocs.io/

Thanks

Comment: Did you installed the package with npm?

Comment: Yes: npm install --save join-monster

Answer (score 2):

You can also import the function like this:

```
const joinMonster = require('join-monster').default;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when making available the library to the file, an object is provided instead of a function.

```js
const joinMonster = require('join-monster');
```

```js
console.log(joinMonster)

// output
{ default: { [Function: joinMonster] getNode: [Function: getNode], version: '2.0.16' } }
```

I don't know why is served an object instead of a function. But
now, I invoke joinMonster.default, and it works:

```js
resolve: (parent, args, context, resolveInfo) => { 
        return joinMonster.default(resolveInfo, {}, sql => {
          return knex.raw(sql)
        })
```